# Converting a Page to a Subsite

Tags: conversion

I initially created an online manual as a page on a share point 2013 site. I now would like to make that same page a sub site to the master site so that I can change permissions. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

## 1 Move it:

1. Create the Subsite
2. Copy / Move the page (.aspx) file to the SitePages library of the new subsite.
3. Set that page as the home page using one of the options here: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-how-to-change-default-home.html

## 2 Or secure it:

*Note: this option will create separate permissions for the page but if you place apps on the page (libraries, calendars, etc.), those apps will inherit permissions from the parent site.*

Pages are files in a library.

1. Select the file.
2. In the FILE ribbon click Shared With.
3. Click Advanced.
4. In the ribbon click Stop Inheriting Permissions.
5. Set the permissions for the desired users.